Rating margin in a document
I'm trying to reproduce this, but I don't have the same thing.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Pour générer du texte de remplissage

\newtcolorbox{exa}[2][]{enhanced,breakable,before skip=2mm,after skip=5mm,
  colback=white!50!white, % Fond plus vif
  colframe=blue!50, % Bordure plus vive
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  attach boxed title to top left ={xshift=0.6cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title={#2},#1,
  boxed title style={frame code={
      \path[fill=blue!30,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}] % Effet d'ombre
      ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
      arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
      ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
      arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
      \path[left color=blue,right color = blue!60!black,
      middle color = blue]
      ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
      [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
      -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
      -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
      [sharp corners]-- cycle;
    },interior engine=empty,
},interior style={top color=white!10!white, bottom color=white!50!white},
  parbox=false,
  left=10mm, % Ajoute une marge à gauche pour les remarques
  before upper={\let\par\relax}, % Pour désactiver les sauts de paragraphe automatiques
  before={\parindent=0pt}} % Pour désactiver l'indentation des paragraphes

  \newcommand{\points}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedright \scriptsize #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exa}[Exercice]

    Soit \( n \) un entier naturel impair. On considère les fonctions \( f_n \) et \( g_n \) définies sur l'intervalle \( I = ]0; +\infty[ \) par :
\[
f_n(x) = (\ln x)^n e^{-x} \quad \text{et} \quad g_n(x) = \frac{n}{x} \ln x.
\]
\points{0.75 pt}
\textbf{Partie I :}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \item Vérifier que \( \lim_{x \to 0^+} f_n(x) = -\infty \) et \( \lim_{x \to +\infty} f_n(x) = 0 \), puis interpréter géométriquement ces résultats.
    \points{0.75 pt}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
        \item Dresser le tableau de variation de la fonction \( g_n \).
        \points{0.75 pt}
        \item Montrer que l'équation \( g_n(x) = 0 \) admet une et une seule solution \( \alpha_n \) dans l'intervalle \( I \).
        \points{0.25 pt}
        \item Déterminer le signe de \( g_n \) sur l'intervalle \( I \).
        \points{0.25 pt}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{exa}

\end{document}

